# Listener doesn't work..It seems the Listener is 0

Tags: java, android, listener

Hey Guys I have this as MainActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public interface LoginListener {
        public void onLoginSuccess();
    }

    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        //logged in and do a few other things
    }
}
```

And that's my second Activity from where I want to call the method onLoginSuccess() in my MainActivity, as you can see I am doing this with an Listener...

```
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

    private LoginActivity.LoginListener mListener;

    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onLoginSuccess();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText((Activity)context, "Listener is 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

MY problem is that I everytime I try it I get back: "Listener is 0" from my Toast...SO what's wrong?

Comment: Where do you set `mListener`? You should set it to the instance of `LoginActivity`. For example, from login activity, do like: `new FingerprintHandler(this)`, where that constructor takes a `LoginListener`. Also, define `LoginListener` separately, and make it so `LoginActivity implements LoginListener`.

Comment: Sorry but how it should be look like? :)

Comment: @Jameson Also I can't do it with LoginActivity implements LoginListener...I have other things in this Activity ..And when I do this I get 86 Errors...

Comment: @Jameson Is there a way to do it without LoginActivity implemets LoginListener?? :)

Comment: Actually your LoginActivity  doesn't implements LoginListener. 
You defined interface LoginListener inside LoginActivity. and than just created a method with same name as in your interface. Why did you do that?

Comment: @user7938448 yes see below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension of my comment above:

You need to register the `mListener` somehow. A pattern to do this is:

```
public class MyHandler {

    private LoginListener mListener;

    public MyHandler(LoginListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    // ... etc...
}
```

Where `LoginListener` is:

```
public interface LoginListener {
    public void onLoginSuccess();
}
```

And your activity has:

```
public MyActivity implements LoginListener {

    // instantiate the handler somewhere, with a reference
    // to "this". "this" refers to the LoginListener interface
    // which is implemented.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Kewel beanZ");
    }
}
```

Or, you can define `LoginListener` as an interface inside the activity if you wish, and instantiate it as:

```
public LoginListener mListener = new LoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sweet sweet baby beanz");
    }
};
```

And instead of using `this`, use `mListener`, when you create `MyHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for Fingerprint authentication in Android

https://gist.github.com/Evin1-/6aca8421903acca0e927eaefd85bd617